# The page isn't redirecting properly using isset

Tags: php, html, mysql, redirect

I'm getting **The page isn't redirecting properly**  in mozilla and in chrome **This webpage has a redirect loop** .

This is what I'm trying to do. In my root directory there is an **index.php** and **information.php** also a folder **common**

Common fodler includes :
common.php , db.php , header.php

In the index.php file in the root this is the code that calls the header.php from common folder.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include('common/header.php');
?>
<p>this is some content in Index file.</p>
```

**common.php**

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    // Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input

    if(isset($_POST['l_submit'])){
        $user = $_POST['l_name'];
        $pass = $_POST['l_pass'];
        $stmt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user and password = $pass");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($stmt);
        // Check username and password match
        if($num_rows > 0) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['l_name'];
        // Jump to secured page
        header('Location:information.php');
        }else{
            echo "<p class='message' align='center'>Wrong Username OR Password...!!</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

and **header.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('common.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>..::University of Westminster::..</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/light.js"></script>

<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script src="js/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/ie6.css"/><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
```

I dont understand why there is a redirect loop occuring I'm calling the **header.php** file in my **index.php** file as you can see and the **header.php** file contain the **isset** function to check if the user exists and redirect also in the **common.php** file I'm setting the session variable.

Comment: Try adding an `exit;` after the `header` functions.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO. Also, your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Nothing is happening same error. I had tried this earlier to stop this loop.

Comment: *sidenote:* never suppress warning / error if you are debugging your codes. Remove those `@`.

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header("Location: $url");` if it is not the last line

Comment: Instead of using include try include_once

Comment: instead of using `include_once`, use `require_once`. Throwing error is better than throwing warning when the file trying to include is missing.

Comment: @all - include_once ,require_once , exit - have tried it all but shows nothing but the same error.

Comment: @Lorenzo read the answer. Your code has logic issue. If the page is not sent by POST method, `$_SESSION['username']` is never assigned, and the `header('Location: index.php')` is reloading `index.php`  **non-stop**

Answer (score 6):

You are redirecting to `index.php`, however `index.php` already has `header.php` included, which has the redirect login.

Try to redirect to a page like `login.php` which does not have `header.php` included.

You can also have a check in header, whether you are already in `index.php` using `PHP_SELF`, and not redirect.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "index.php")) {
  header("Location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the above logic, OP is better to re-design the flow.

Comment: @Raptor : i agree with your opinion.

Comment: Ok, I have given the check in `header.php`, so OP can go with current design

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a session for a user that is logged in, you'll toss them around endlessly.

In your index you include header.php, which if you aren't logged in will send you back to index.php, where the same issue applies as long as there's no session. 
Since you're being tossed around endlessly you don't get any chance of making this session.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work with the current logic . I just had to alter index.php and rest stays the same.

in **index.php**

```
<?php 
include_once('common/db.php');
include_once('common/common.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header("Location: information.php");
}
?>
<section>
   <div class="row">
...
.
```

I checked here whether the session is set and redirected it to **information.php** file.

Comment: That's incorrect. Your `header()` function sends the rest of the page to `information.php` too. Remember to add `exit` after `header('Location: xxx');`. Also, as said, `require_once()` is better than `include_once()`

Comment: @Raptor Yes sure will deifnately do that . Thanks again for the help really appreciate.